# Tag synonym request: ef5

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Please add the synonym [ef5](/questions/tagged/ef5) == [entity-framework-5](/questions/tagged/entity-framework-5).
I don't have enough rep in both these to suggest this officially.

Comment: You're the only user who has tagged a question with [ef5]. Why not retag your own question to the other tag? Then [ef5] will be gone within a day.

Comment: I thought the purpose of tag synonyms was to make it easier for people to use shortcuts.  e.g. it's easier to type "ef5" than "entity-framework-5".  So why not create that synonym and make it easier for users to tag their questions?

Comment: They exist to group variations of the same tag together. I don't know if the whole shortcut idea is one of their purposes or just a side-effect. I would think it's not all that difficult to just select the appropriate existing tag to begin with, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonym tags are thought to be used when there are users who use different tags that have the same meaning, not to provide shortcuts to existing tags. There is no need to have shortcuts, as when you add a tag to a question, the tag name is autocompleted. You don't need to write the tag name completely: Just write part of its name (enough to have a restricted list that includes the tag you want to use), and select the tag from the list shown you.

[image: screenshot]

Such shortcuts would be also problematic, as there could be more than one tag for which a shortcut suits, which would mean that users could use a shortcut to obtain the wrong tag.